# C# Visual Studio Test With -> Debugger context menu disappeared

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, testing

I have a test class with some test methods in my C# (Visual Studio 2012) solution. I always right clicked the test method and chose: `Test With -> Debugger`. But suddenly that option disappeared. I must have accidentally pressed a hotkey or something?

[image]

Does someone know how to get this back? Or maybe an alternative to run with the debugger? Now I can only choose 'Run Tests' and 'Debug Tests'.

Comment: Debug Tests should give the same outcome. i.e. it'll debug the one test you've right-clicked.

Comment: Oh it does. I'm sorry, apologies. Could have figured that out myself. That option didn't work for me due to something else, when I tried it earlier. But it does now.

Comment: Debug Tests should do the same thing but I think `Test With -> Debugger` is something added with the testdriven.net plugin.